# Python: how to efficiently convert multiple-level date variables into binary?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with dependent variable being date like `'1/23/16'`, `'2002/4/16'` or `NA`, I just want to convert all values not `NA` into `1` and `NA` into `0`. 
How can I do that efficiently? I don't want do it like this, not mention following codes don't work for some values like `"2/18/16"`, `"2001/4/16"`, really don't why.

```
for i, date in enumerate(data.completed_date):
 if not pd.isnull(date):
     data.completed_date[i] = 1
 else:
     data.completed_date[i] = 0
```

Update: the head of this column

2          NaN
3    2002/3/16
4          NaN
5          NaN
6      1/23/16

Comment: You could have a try with `pd.where` and `pd.fillna` for example. Also what do you mean by "don't work"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the info. 'don;t work' means these values won't change to 1 after implementing above codes

Comment: Paste the output from `df.head()` in your question. If your values are `"NA"`, then that is not a recognized `null` format. Recognized `null` formats are `numpy.nan`, `None`. Hence your `pd.isnull` will not work. You will have to either typecast your variables or get clever with your `if` statements. I would recommend typecasting. The output of `pd.head()` will help us help you typecast your data such that `pd.isnull` will work. Also, here is a tip: all `pandas` methods work on the whole column, you need not use a loop.

Comment: I think I have found way for this problem: first I indeed use df.fillna() to deal with all NA cells, then I use code like df.col[condition] = 1 to fill all other cells. More than that I use pd.to_datetime(col) to convert all values in this column into unified datetime, and at last I convert this col to mumeric. Seems not very cool. but it did work.